# Using requests to automate "logging" into a server

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to create a bot that joins the server by putting in a name and pressing a button that connects the request into the server., but in requests. The system hasn't been working as supposed to. It is supposed to `POST` the information in the correct places with the json.

```py
payload = {
 'idOftheInputBar': 'Username'
}
```

After that, I tried posting, getting, and patching but the response ended up with `404` or `200` but didn't send. How can make a request join the public server after putting in a username?

Comment: What's the problem description? Also, where's the code?

Comment: @rv.kvetch there is no need of code as it is a simple as `x = requests.post`, I just need help actually performing the action.

Comment: I still didn't really understand what the ask here is.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I edited the question, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: making a post request won't click a button for you. does that button trigger a post request?

Comment: The problem is I need to re-read the question a few times for the ask to really sink in; and unfortunately I am not any better off for having done so.

Comment: No, thanks for helping. @Einliterflasche